# I have problem in magento installatiion

Tags: magento-1.8

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\production\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php on
>   line 1236

```
$config = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->{$group};
```

> Notice: Undefined index: _resource_singleton/core/store in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\production\app\Mage.php on line 255

```
public static function registry($key)
{

    if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
        return self::$_registry[$key];
    }

    die(self::$_registry[$key]);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Git ?